# How to use the LinkedIn API to extract and store company data?

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

I want to use the LinkedIn API to extract some company data (no more than a couple of records) including basic information such as the company name, size and website. I already have an OAuth access token but I don't know how to use to retrieve the data.

I tried looking for ways to use the API but currently there are no examples in the documentation (https://linkedin-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html). From within the documentation it appears that data about a company can be fetched using get_company(public_id) but the public_id is no longer present in the URL of a company on LinkedIn. Where shall I obtain the company URLs from in such case and how to extract the company data for multiple companies at a time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.